# Weighted mean based on correlation

Tags: correlation, mean

I have three time series data $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ that are correlated with $Y$ as follows: $0.95, 0.75, 0.65$. I want to make a weighted mean of the three time series based on their correlation with $Y$ to make $X_4$. In effect, $X_4$ is the ensemble mean but weighted according to their correlation with $Y$. To make a simple mean is counter-intuitive to the fact that $X_1$ has the highest correlation with $Y$ and its effects will be diluted by $X_3$.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You will probably get a more helpful answer if you explained what you were trying to achieve. The short answer is that you should use X1, X2 and X3 to forecast Y and then use the fitted values, but how one does that (and whether it is a good idea) would depend on your purpose.

Comment: These are three forecast time series. Considering X1 has the highest correlation with Y1, I would choose X1. But I find that X2 and X3 still has some merit and I do not want to discount both in the ensemble mean so I am asking if there is a method to create a weighted mean using the correlation values.

My first take is like this:

mean = x1*0.5+x2*0.3+x3*0.2

X1 is the time series with highest correlation, X2 has the second highest, X3 has the least correlation. This way, I am putting more weight to the data with highest correlation than simple mean where their weight is equal.

Comment: There's just not enough information (yet) to provide good advice.  This *could* be framed as a regression problem (how to find a linear combination of the $X_i$ with the greatest correlation with $Y$) and, if so, the solution depends on the covariances among the $X_i.$  It's not clear (yet) whether this is your objective, though.

Comment: Thank you @PeterEllis